# How can I activate my VS Code extension only when a workspace is opened?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I am writing a VS Code extension which is only useful when a workspace is open. It relies specifically on `ExtensionContext.storageUri` being defined (ie `!== undefined`) and at least one folder being part of that workspace.

I want to avoid having to check the existence of a workspace and content each time I need to interact with it.

Looking at the [available activation events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events) I'm unsure on the best way to achieve what I need. Maybe using `workspaceContains` for if any files exist?

```
"workspaceContains:**/*"
```

At the moment I am using `onStartupFinished`, which appears to be emitted when a new workspace is opened (as opposed to only when VS Code is explicitly quit and reopened), which is great. But when a workspace isn't open it means that my extensions' `activate()` function will have to handle this and leave the extension active without any functionality for the user to make use of. It doesn't feel right. Unless I throw an error of course, but I am not sure thats the right solution here either.

Comment: working with VSC without a workspace open is a case that will not happen often, just active the extension when VSC is started, you can use activation `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `activationEvent` pattern you suggested seems to work properly, and the extension is activated only for non-empty workspaces. However, starting at 1.74 release (Nov 2022), VS Code added a new feature for extension developers called [Implicit Activation Events](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_74#_implicit-activation-events-for-declared-extension-contributions), which means that the extension will be activated *even if you forgot* to include some of the events you contributed, to the `activationEvents` property. In the end, no matter if you *didn't add* some command to `activationEvents`. When the user calls it, the extension will be activated, even on an empty workspace.

As an alternative, you could use [When Clause Contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts) to *disable* commands, but you still need to add some code/checks for this to work.

That being said, with the current API and with the latest Implicit Activation Events feature, I don't see how you could accomplish what you need. You will have to add *some checking* for empty workspaces on your extension.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @alefragnani. I appreciate you highlighting the Implicit Activation Events as I didn't know about this, but it explains the behaviour I have been seeing (which is as you describe).

As it happens, I have already implemented something similar to what you suggest, using `when` clauses and it's working quite nicely.